# ExpressJs return sharp file

Tags: express, sharp

I'm creating an endpoint in my rest api with expressJs that resizes the passed image.

The endpoint only works with images that are in a database.

Endpoint: domain/image-resize?width=number&height=number

When I test in insomnia (img 1), the img is shown in the return, as expected, but this process I'm using to show the image in the  tag with vuejs, that is, I'm passing the image returned by the api in the src of the .

But it looks like I'm doing something wrong because a type of string (img 2) is returned that is not possible to use in the  tag

**Images** I don't have the reputation to post images, but here's the question in the lib with the imgs [link](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/3397)

**code**

```
   const transform = await sharp(imageBuffer).toFormat('png').resize(currentWidth, currentHeight)
    
    res.type(`${currentFormat}`)
    res.status(200)
    return transform.pipe(res)
```

I'm doing it in a way that I don't need to create a file on the server side to be able to return, do you know how I can do it in this case?

img vuejs code (using response.data)

```
<img :src="currentImage" width="300"
      />
```

Comment: can you add the code on how your showing the image (vue/html part), it a bit unclear

Comment: cool, does `currentImage` equal a string, ie a path to the `/image-resize?width=number&height=number` or are you fetching the image with ajax and inserting binary into src? an error message or screenshot would help

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I think you just answered my biggest question. (what is this large code that is returned), it is a binary, it seems that by default insomnia and the browser know how to render but I need to convert it to show in the img tag. Would it be correct to return base64? And yes, I was taking the binary and putting it in src kk

Comment: if you use a path to the image it will work fine, put `transform` or the buffer into a var associated with the image i.e images[a unique id] = {buffer: transform.toBuffer(), width, height} then return the id so it can be used in the URL then fetched from mem, if you want to load image via ajax or such your need make use of createObjectURL then pass the data to it here little example with socket.io instead of ajax https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-leaf-kc1iqr?file=/src/client/index.html